# How do I read from a Serial Port, without using up its resource?

Tags: monitoring, serial-port

My boss at work needs to be making a monitoring app for a program they are using. Because of their business needs, I can **NOT** use any sort of virtual serial port. The data goes in and out of /dev/ttyUSB0, and the application **MUST** be connected to /dev/ttyUSB0.

I have already discussed a design that utilizes virtual serial ports created by socat so I can get what goes in and out the serial port, without interrupting the transfer of data. But that design was rejected. And he suggested that I make it through something called Port Mirroring or Reading the information without using up the resource like apparently Putty can do in Windows.

I am a huge lost at what to do, or how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to monitor in hardware.  However, in software, I think you can rename the tty to be a pty instead!   `/dev` filenames are not magic-they are friendly ways of referring to drivers by number.  Make a Pty (or Unix-domain socket), rename the real tty (/dev/ttyUSB0) to `/dev/magicserial`, and rename your new endpoint to the name of the real tty.  Then you are totally in control!  Write a daemon that runs a`select`  loop to copy all data between magicserial and your endpoint, and you can monitor whatever you want.  Not trivial, but it should work fine.

Here's [an example Pty tutorial](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html).